# Can not Get Hour from showTimePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

ShowTimePicker is easy and understandable, but I don't know where this error came from.

The code:

```
TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
    
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.access_time, color: Colors.blue),
               onPressed: () async {
                                  TimeOfDay? _time = await showTimePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                                  );
                                  if (_time != null) {
                                    selectedTime.hour = _time.hour;
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
```

The error shows under hour word in `selectedTime.hour`:

```
'hour' can't be used as a setter because it's final.  Try finding a different setter, or making 'hour' non-final.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you go to definition of class TimeOfDay you'll see hour is final so you can not reset this property. But you just reset selectedTime (both hour and minute will reset). Then in initialTime property you should check selectedTime and set like below code if it's not null. Each Time pick time you'll keep last value.

```
 onPressed: () async {
        TimeOfDay? _time = await showTimePicker(
          context: context,
          initialTime:
              selectedTime != null ? selectedTime : TimeOfDay.now(),
        );
        if (_time != null) {
          selectedTime = _time;
          // selectedTime.hour = _time.hour;
          print(selectedTime.hour);
        }
      },
```

Comment: It works thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replacing()` method.

> Returns a new TimeOfDay with the hour and/or minute replaced.

```dart
  onPressed: () async {
          TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();

          TimeOfDay? _time = await showTimePicker(
            context: context,
            initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
          );
          if (_time != null) {
            selectedTime = selectedTime.replacing(hour: _time.hour); // use setState if neended
          }

          print(selectedTime.toString());
        },
```

For more [TimeOfDay-replacing](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay/replacing.html)

Comment: Your way also works. thanks :)